# Javascript equivalent of jQuery's .detach() function

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a JavaScript function which does the same thing as jQuery's `detach()` (detach an element from DOM without removing it).  I came across [this](https://gist.github.com/cowboy/938767), but it's not an officially supported function.  Does JavaScript have a function similar to `.detach()` that is built in?

Comment: _Does JavaScript have a function similar to .detach() that is built in?_: Answer: No.

Comment: Don't forget jQuery is a Javascript library. You could read the source code of jQuery's detach function and try re-implement the behaviour.

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/662083ed7bfea6bad5f9cd4060dab77c1f32aacd/src/manipulation.js

Comment: Just to be more (perhaps excruciatingly and unnecessarily) precise about this, JavaScript _itself_ doesn't have any methods for manipulating the DOM at all. It's the DOM that provides such methods. The better question would be if there's a standard DOM method similar to jQuery's `detach`.

Answer (score 22):

Something like this?

```
function detach(node) {
  return node.parentElement.removeChild(node);
}
```

or, even you can just use `node.parentElement.removeChild(node)`

Brief explanation. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)

> The Node.removeChild() method removes a child node from the DOM. Returns removed node.
>
> The removed child node still exists in memory, but is no longer part of the DOM.  ... you may reuse the removed node later in your code....

Comment: That looks very useful

Comment: Does this save events and data?

Comment: @Toniq, on the [same page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild): _Unlike Node.cloneNode() the return value preserves the EventListener objects associated with it._ Data attached to the removed node (like `mynode.foo="bar"`) is still there. (I guess) `parent.removeChild` in the child node sets the reference to the parent node to null, and in the parent node removes the reference to the child node from its list of child nodes. Data is not copied around. [element.remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) behaves similar.